# Apache Flink cast exception when deployed to AWS Kinesis Data Analytics

Tags: apache-flink, classloader, amazon-kinesis

We are prototyping Flink to do some basic analytics.

We are consuming from 2 Kinesis streams inside the same Job when deployed. When I run locally using custom sources to generate data, everything works.

When I switch to consuming from Kinesis (so now i guess deserialization is involved) either locally or deployed, I get:

```
class org.flink.analytics.model.meterdata.EnrichedMessage cannot be cast to class org.flink.analytics.model.MeterEventWrapperMessage (org.flink.analytics.model.meterdata.EnrichedMessage and org.flink.analytics.model.MeterEventWrapperMessage are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I read https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/ops/debugging/debugging_classloading/ and tried to apply the parent-first setting via:

```
Properties confProperties = new Properties();
confProperties.put("execution.target", "local");
confProperties.put("execution.attached", "true");
confProperties.put("parallelism.default", 20);
confProperties.put("classloader.resolve-order", "parent-first");
Configuration c = ConfigurationUtils.createConfiguration(confProperties);
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(1, c);
```

Just to see if I could fix the issue.... no luck.

The types are just Pojo, and i register the FlinkKinesisConsumer with SimpleStringSchema and then deserialize with objectmapper - but I guess that's not where this issue is happening?

Any ideas? Am i doing something not really supported by Flink? Multiple Kinesis sources in a single job?